# jQuery slideDown vs. jQuery UI .show('slide')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to utilize jQuery's built in effect functionality to create a "drawer" that slides out from behind a navigation bar, pushing the content below it out of the way.

If I use `$('#drawer').slideDown()`, the content is pushed out of the way, but the content does not actually "slide down." It's more of a wipe to reveal the content.

If I use `$('#drawer').show('slide',{direction:'up'})`, the content correctly slides down, but all of the content below the element jumps out of the way before the effect occurs.

Is there a way to combine the best of both of these to replicate the effect I'm looking for: a drawer that slides out, pushing the content below it out of the way?

I've investigated jQuery UI's `.animate()` function, but the documentation is unhelpful. My crude efforts to utilize it have been fraught with failure.

And, in case anyone asks, sorry, I can't show an example, but we would like it to function like the jQuery Drawer plugin:

http://lib.metatype.jp/jquery_drawer/sample.html

But that plugin doesn't do quite what we need either, otherwise I'd just use that (not using a bulleted list or AJAX content). The effect there is what we want, however.

UPDATE: I have also tried this part of the code via the jQuery Drawer plugin, but it doesn't animate at all:

```
$('#drawer').css({ marginTop: $('#drawer').height() * -1 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 });
```

To clarify, too, this is called within a function `OpenDrawer()` that is called thusly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    OpenDrawer();
});
```

Because by default it will load when the page loads.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're looking for an effect more like 'blind':

```
$('#drawer').show('blind');
```

It's odd that $.fn.slideDown() and $.fn.show('slide') don't operate the same way, but rather 'blind' does.  'slide' creates a placeholder the size of your object and then slides into the frame of view, while blind adjusts the height or width of your element until it expands to the  correct size (while overflow is set to hidden).  So actually, the effect names are correct, but there's some confusion because of the legacy name $.fn.slideDown().

Comment: I've been searching for this for AGES! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

It is a late post, but I encountered this problem and managed to make something that works.

I'm not a jQuery or Javascript Guru so don't be harsh with this quick solution.

Here is a little example.
The order of the effects must respected.
You can play with the animation time length to have a really nice drawing effect.

I just quickly tested it on FF 3.6

You can try the example on the google code playground.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jqueryui

Click on edit html, paste the code and click run code.
The example should be working

Hope it'll help

```
<html>
<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.6.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
jQuery(function ()
{
    // We bind the <a>I'm the push link!</a> click event to the toggle function
    $("#topPart a").click(function() 
                                      {
                                          toggleSlide(this);
                                      });                
});
function toggleSlide(element)
{
    var drawer = jQuery("#drawer");
    var content = jQuery("#drawerContent");
    if (jQuery(content).is(":hidden"))
    {
        // The order here is important, we must slide juste before starting blinding
        setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        jQuery(content).effect("slide", { direction: "up", mode : "show"}, 500);
                    },1);
        setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        jQuery(drawer).effect("blind", { direction: "vertical", mode : "show" }, 490);

                    },1);
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        jQuery(drawer).effect("blind", { direction: "vertical", mode : "hide" }, 500);
                        // The previous blind effect hide the drawer
                        // However we want it to be shown again, if not the next "drawer opening effect" won't play
                        jQuery(drawer).effect("blind", { direction: "vertical", mode : "show" }, 1);
                    },1);
        setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        jQuery(content).effect("slide", { direction: "up", mode : "hide" }, 460);
                    },1);
    }
}

</script>

    <div id="topPart">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">I'm the push link!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="drawer">
        <div id="drawerContent" style="display:none;border:1px solid transparent;width:600px;">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, ....
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomPart">
    I want to be pushed nicely
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Been looking for something like this (a true slide down effect) for AGES.

Comment: @katebp, I truly agree with you and thumbs up for `grifos`.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript you have in your question update works, but it needs to operate on an element containing your content rather than the content itself.

To see this in action, surround the element `#drawer` with another `div`:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='drawer'>...</div>
<div>
```

And animate the container:

```
$('#container')
    .css({ marginTop: $('#container').height() * -1 })
    .animate({ marginTop: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is like the accordion behavior except that you can also slide it up. I have used this functionality to create what I think you are looking for.

`$('#drawer').slideDown('slow');`

By changing the speed you can get different slide speeds to look the way you want it. Now, even though you have the drawer element, you need a container that is initially hidden which is what will slide. Lets say you have a button with an id of "drawer", and a container with an id of "myDrawerContent." You would do the following,

```
$('#drawer').click(function() {
    $('#myDrawerContent').slideDown('slow');
}
```

```
$('#drw_loader').animate({ 
    height: $('#drw_ajax').height() }, 
    function () { $('#drw_loader').fadeOut(function () { $('#drw_ajax').fadeIn(); });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Metropolis

Comment: Well, this isn't really my issue either. slideDown() works fine, but it's not actually "sliding." It's more of a "wipe" effect. This is all well and good for a lot of purposes, but I want the content to appear to slide down, not to appear to be "revealed."

Comment: That link that you showed (http://lib.metatype.jp/jquery_drawer/sample.html) is using animate. I will post it above.

Comment: That's closer, but I think it's the wrong part of the jQuery Drawer code. That's for closing the loader once AJAX content has loaded. I tried borrowing a line earlier in the code (see changed question), but that doesn't work at all. I feel like I'm on the right track, but this still isn't really close to working yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a decent implementation of this (seemingly simple) effect too, and this is the best one I've found:
http://eric.muyser.com/work/jquery/drawer/example/

See here for more info/code/etc:
http://eric.muyser.com/blog/post/jquery-plugin-jdrawer

However, it still seems overkill and needs to be boiled down into a bare essence animation plugin that can be called/applied via .show(), which is precisely what you'd expect to be already present in jQuery/UI as standard in the first place... but sadly isn't...