# slideUp where the top of the div is revealed last

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

jQuery's `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions are very handy, but I need to alter their behaviour a little.

**What it does**

What normally happens when you call `slideDown` on a `div` is that the div slides down, and as it slides futher down, the lower contents of the `div` are revealed.

**What I need it to do**

I would like the `div` to slide down, but instead of revealing the lower contents of the `div`, the upper contents should be revealed. So the bottom-most contents should be visible first, then the upper contents should slide into view. The point of this is to make the `div` look like it is being slid onto the screen from off of the screen. Here is a diagram:

```
How it works now:
----------
| Line 1 | |  Reveals from top to bottom; top is anchored in place
| Line 2 | |  As the div expands vertically, Line 1 is shown first and
| Line 3 | |  none of the lines move as they become visible.
********** V
| Line 4 | 
| Line 5 |
----------

How I would like it to work:
----------
| Line 1 |    
| Line 2 |    
| Line 3 |    
********** ^  Reveals from bottom to top; bottom is anchored in place
| Line 4 | |  As the div expands vertically, the Line 5 is shown first and
| Line 5 | |  moves downward as more is revealed.
----------
```

I realise that I might not be communicating that effectively, please let me know if you need more clarification.

**Update:**

Here is the HTML that is equivalent to what I am working with:

```
<div id="anchored">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- this is the div that is initially invisible and should slide from the bottom -->
                <div id="slider">
                    hello
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <!-- this is always visible and should be pushed down by "slider" as it moves downward -->
            hello 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#anchored {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#slider {
    display: none;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted it yourself?

Comment: @Armatus I have no idea how to attempt it.

Comment: You could have a look at `animate()` and see if you can build on that. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ (or http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). Otherwise, jQuery's code is open and you could see how they do the sliding and try and do make your own sliding of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it to work using a combination of Armatus and tea_totaler's answers, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg4yN/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something akin to the following, but given that you've not shown your HTML this can only be a suggestion (rather than a specific answer, though if you post your actual HTML then I can try to offer something that will serve better):

```
var container = $('#slide'),
    p = container.find('p');

container.height(p.height());
$(p).css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : -p.height()
}).animate({
    'top' : 0
},2500);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x7SH8/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="slide">
<p><!-- contents... --></p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#slide {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

References:

1. jQuery:

   - [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
   - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
2. CSS:

   - [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow).
   - [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position).

Comment: Thanks, but there are things below the `div` that need to slide down as the hidden `div` reveals. Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/x7SH8/3/ the "hey" should not instantly be at the position it will end up at.

Comment: Then you really need to show your html in your question, to allow us to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

slideDown and slideUp won't help. You'll have t hack your way around. Wrap the expandable block in some dummy parent div & set it's overflow to hidden. Then position your expandable block inside that dummy parent such that only 5h item is visible.

When you wish to change the state of your div, first set the height of your parent dummy div equal to its child and then use animate() your div's top position attribute to 0.

If you can give me the HTML markup and CSS code on jsFiddle, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

One quick idea (I have no idea whether this is valid; I will test later): Maybe you can put the text into one div which is of constant height. Wrap this with another div which is the one you slideDown and Up. Attach the constant height div to the bottom of the wrapper using position:relative (or absolute) and bottom:0. With overflow:hidden in the wrapper the whole thing might work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do what you want and I think having an option for the slideDown method to handle this would be great. Anyway, you can do it like this:

```
$('div').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
```

See it in action on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7SH8/) (using jQuery UI). Inspired by [JQuery: How to perform a "push" slide, not a slide up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701770/jquery-how-to-perform-a-push-slide-not-a-slide-up)

Comment: That seems to be jQuery UI; if so, it might be worth mentioning that.

Comment: I think this will be the answer but I am having some trouble, I'll try to give an example of what's happening...

Comment: You can see the problem I am having here: http://jsfiddle.net/x7SH8/2/  the divs that are below it need to slide down smoothly also.

Comment: @DavidThomas Forgot I'd used it, thanks for mentioning. Answer updated.

Comment: @SethCarnegie take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014916/jquery-slidedown-vs-jquery-ui-showslide - looks like it meets your requirements.

Comment: @cchana thanks, but I actually solved this myself in what looks (after a cursory glance at the question you linked to) like a little simpler of a way. You can see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it and use .slideDown() too. You'll just need to wrap the item you want to use .slideDown on in a relatively positioned element (e.g. a div) and then set the positioning on your element to absolute, and then tie it to the bottom of the parent by setting the CSS bottom property to zero.

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2Xzb2/)**.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#foo{
    border:1px solid #999;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}
```

​
jQuery:

```
$('#foo').hide().slideDown(3000);​
```

Comment: This is close, but if it does what jsfiddle shows, then it's backwards. I need the top to stay anchored and the bottom to move, but the bottom contents to show first and the top to show last.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case I think you'll need to use animate to change the top position of the element, masking it behind another element.